# Programmatically adding entries to Windows 7 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

How does one add entries to the Windows 7 start menu for All Users programatically?  For example I might want to add the folder MyApps containing a shortcut to myapp.exe and a URL for www.myapp.com.

Ideally I'd like to do this in a batch file but I'll take VBScript or PowerShell as well please.

Comment: Keep in mind that your program will have to run with elevated permissions to write to those folders.

Answer (score 2):

To add entries to the All Programs portion, merely include a shortcut under the folder %AllUserProfile%\Microsoft\Start Menu\Programs.

You can use the SpecialFolder object in VBScript.

Not sure how to do it in Powershell, but this is it in Javascript:

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var allUserProfilePath = shell.SpecialFolders("CommonPrograms");
var myShortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(allUserProfilePath + "\\myShortcut.lnk");
myShortcut.TargetPath = "c:\\My Programs Path";
myShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\Blah";
myShortcut.WindowStyle = 4;
myShortcut.Save();
```

The translation to VB is straight forward

```
Dim shell 
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim allUserProfilePath 
Set allUserProfilePath = shell.SpecialFolders("CommonPrograms")
Dim myShortcut 
Set myShortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(allUserProfilePath + "\myShortcut.lnk")
myShortcut.TargetPath = "c:\My Programs Path"
myShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "c:\Blah"
myShortcut.WindowStyle = 4
myShortcut.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are functions in VB and PS to target system folders like the All Users Desktop, All Users Start Menu, etc.

In VBscript you'll want to use [SpecialFolders](http://ss64.com/vb/special.html) and in PowerShell use [Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html).

The following is a snip of code I use to call a function DeleteFile, and pass it the location of a file on the AllUsersDesktop:

```
DeleteFile (objShell.SpecialFolders ("AllUsersDesktop") & "\Microsoft Word 2010.lnk")
```